# Error while Installing packages wordcloud and tm

Tags: r, tm, cran

while installing packages like tm, wordcloud I get error slam not available for this version, please guide me in installing tm and wordcloud packages.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/431380/how-to-install-upgrade-r-base

Comment: @RomanLuštrik the above link steps would install 3.2.1.

Comment: wil Ubuntu 12.04 support R 3.3.1

Comment: You should adapt the codename to reflect the version. See https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README

Comment: @RomanLuštrik
Do I need to upgrade ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04??